# Cannot build rosjava (on mac) -without- ROS installed?

Tags: ros, build, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to build rosjava  (OS X 10.6.8, 32-bit, Java 1.6 without installation of ROS) based on this [rosjava tutorial](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html).

I was successfull to install it on Ubuntu 12 with Fuerte installed, everything worked.

But now, on Mac, after running:

```
./gradlew install
```

the maven repostitory on robotbrains seems to be down, i get:

```
    :apache_xmlrpc_common:compileJava
Checksum missing at http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient/3.1.0/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.pom.sha1 due to: Connection to http://robotbrains.hideho.org refused
Checksum missing at http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public/org/apache/ws/commons/ws-commons-util/1.0.1/ws-commons-util-1.0.1.pom.sha1 due to: Connection to http://robotbrains.hideho.org refused

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':apache_xmlrpc_common:compile'.
> Could not resolve group:org.apache.commons, module:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient, version:3.1.0.
  Required by:
      ros.rosjava_core:apache_xmlrpc_common:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
   > Could not GET 'http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public/org/apache/commons/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient/3.1.0/com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient-3.1.0.pom'.
> Could not resolve group:org.apache.ws.commons, module:ws-commons-util, version:1.0.1.
  Required by:
      ros.rosjava_core:apache_xmlrpc_common:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
   > Could not GET 'http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public/org/apache/ws/commons/ws-commons-util/1.0.1/ws-commons-util-1.0.1.pom'.
```

I found [this solution](http://answers.ros.org/question/42748/rosjava_core-build-error-apache_xmlrpc_commoncompile/) but it causes these further errors:

```
...
:rosjava_messages:jar
:rosjava:compileJava
/Users/j/workspace/HANNS/network/rosjava/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/node/RosoutLogger.java:36: package rosgraph_msgs does not exist
  private final Publisher<rosgraph_msgs.Log> publisher;
                                       ^
/Users/j/workspace/HANNS/network/rosjava/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/node/RosoutLogger.java:45: package rosgraph_msgs does not exist
  public Publisher<rosgraph_msgs.Log> getPublisher() {
                                ^
/Users/j/workspace/HANNS/network/rosjava/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/time/ClockTopicTimeProvider.java:26: package rosgraph_msgs does not exist
import rosgraph_msgs.Clock;
                    ^
/Users/j/workspace/HANNS/network/rosjava/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/time/ClockTopicTimeProvider.java:36: package rosgraph_msgs does not exist
  private final Subscriber<rosgraph_msgs.Clock> subscriber;
                                        ^
/Users/j/workspace/HANNS/network/rosjava/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/time/ClockTopicTimeProvider.java:39: package rosgraph_msgs does not exist
  private rosgraph_msgs.Clock clock;
                       ^
...
```

(and 22 similar ones)

So, this means that on this maven repository are some old libraries, or rosjava is not that standalone and needs ROS installation on a computer too? :(

(Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade Java to newer version, because it seems that 1.7 is not supported for 32-bit systems)

Thank you very much for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42975/cannot-build-rosjava-(on-mac)--without--ros-installed??/) by [jrd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3136/jrd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, problem solved, turns out that the rosjava depends on several ROS (mainly low level communication) libraries.

so i copied folder /opt/ros/fuerte/include (from ROS barebones installation for Ubuntu) onto Mac, exported the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and then installation succeeds:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/path/to/folder/include/
./gradlew install
```

---

Originally posted by [jrd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3136/jrd/) with karma: 46 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1